# Python: SSH with Hamachi

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I want to connect to a server which is given by LogMeIn Hamachi. If I use "ssh xy@xzh.local" in the command prompt than I get access to it. However this does not work in python with paramiko.

If I try to do the same in python with paramiko:
`ssh.connect(hostname='xy@xzh.local', username='', password='mypassword')`
then I get the following Error: getaddrinfo failed.

However, If I look in Hamachi and copy the IP Adress of that specific station to my python script:
`ssh.connect(hostname='IP ADRESS', username='', password='mypassword')`
I get "Ip Adress" not found in known_hosts.

What can I do? I have access when using the normal CMD from windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh.connect(hostname='xy@xzh.local', username='', password='mypassword')` seems incorrect - the `hostname` includes your username and an `@` symbol.

Does this work?

```
ssh.connect(hostname='xzh.local', username='xy', password='mypassword')
```

Your second issue, when you try to connect via IP, the error is different: address not in known hosts. You can get around this via 2 methods:

Ignore host verification:

```
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
```

or by adding the host's key before connecting:

```
client.get_host_keys().add('example.com', 'ssh-rsa', key)
```

The latter should be your preferred choice - disabling security features of ssh (the s stands for secure!) is usually not the way to go. If you've already connected to xzh.local via ssh, that hosts's key should already be in you known_hosts file.